# SP Host web look not propagated to chrome control in add-in web

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, provider-hosted-app, azure

I have a provider hosted add-in which uses chrome control. Previously, if I changed the look of SP host web, that change would propagate to add-in web too and chrome control would update. This is similar to what is mentioned in [this MS docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/give-your-provider-hosted-add-in-the-sharepoint-look-and-feel#run-the-add-in-and-test-the-new-sharepoint-ui) (point# 8)

Now it has stopped working and the look does not change. Any idea what might have changed?